# Authentication HttpClient

Tags: java, authentication, post, get, httpclient

I am trying test one simple authentication in my local gitlab with Apache HTTPClient.
No erros is dispatched and i am redirect to login page:

Code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.ParseException;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.params.ClientPNames;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class SimpleFormAuth {

public static void main(String[] args){

      String host = "localhost";
      int port = 8083;
      String protocol = "http";

      DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

      try {
          //GET para pegar os cookies ta tela de login
          HttpHost httpHost = new HttpHost(host, port, protocol);
          client.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.DEFAULT_HOST, httpHost);

          HttpGet securedResource = new HttpGet("/");           
          HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(securedResource);
          HttpEntity responseEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
          String strResponse = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
          int statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
          EntityUtils.consume(responseEntity);


          //POST de autenticação
          HttpPost authpost = new HttpPost("/users/sign_in");
          authpost.addHeader("User-Agent",
                  "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:34.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/34.0");
          authpost.addHeader("Accept",
                  "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
          authpost.addHeader("Accept-Language", "pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
          authpost.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
          authpost.addHeader("Referer", "http://localhost:8083/users/sign_in");
          authpost.addHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");

          List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("utf8", "&#x2713;"));
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("authenticity_token", "token_capturado_do_get"));
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_login", "login_de_teste"));
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_password", "senha_de_teste"));
          nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_remember_me", "0"));
          authpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"UTF-8"));

          httpResponse = client.execute(authpost);
          responseEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
          strResponse = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
          statusCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
          EntityUtils.consume(responseEntity);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Update post with html form:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/sign_in" class="new_user" id="new_user" method="post"><div style="display:none"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="9BHyiC9DRrI0EHCeamiW0zQC4qi+eTr6KmsONEMf3PQ=" /></div><input autofocus="autofocus" class="form-control top" id="user_login" name="user[login]" placeholder="Username or Email" type="text" />
<input class="form-control bottom" id="user_password" name="user[password]" placeholder="Password" type="password" />
<div class='clearfix append-bottom-10'>
<label class='checkbox remember_me' for='user_remember_me'>
<input name="user[remember_me]" type="hidden" value="0" /><input id="user_remember_me" name="user[remember_me]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<span>Remember me</span>
</label>
</div>
<div>
<input class="btn-save btn" name="commit" type="submit" value="Sign in" />
<div class='pull-right'>
<a class="btn" href="/users/password/new">Forgot your password?</a>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

With form authentication i will get success in login?